# Building a CSV file to import into sql, how to handle relationships?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have a very large set of data where each row in table A point to a lot of rows in table B. In generating a CSV file, I would need to somehow show this relation, but I don't have an integer based pkey. Each of the items in A have a unique username, and the same goes for table B (that is, table B has its own unique set of names).

I am working with Python and Postgres if that matters.
Another note, both tables are 50-100M+ rows long, about 8 columns each.

Is there a good strategy for building out this CSV file?

Comment: How are the rows in each table actually related in real life? Showing some actual sample data might make this easier to answer.

Comment: @TomH The data consists of git repository logs I generate. In terms of structure: there is a Commits table which points to a Repository (its own table) and then for each file changed in a Commit there is a set of changes written to the Changes table.

Comment: Your question and content is a little confusing. Hence, showing current and desired results always help! Does data currently reside in Postgre tables and you need to create one csv file? Or does data reside in csv files and you need to import them to Postgre and need to somehow map relationships?

Comment: CSV files just contain lines of data. You can't "show" a relatonship in a CSV file. Are you asking how to design the tables that this data is going to be imported into?

Answer (score 1):

You say each row has a unique name. If they truly are unique then you can use them as keys for your tables. You don't need integer-based keys.

For example, the path to a file can be considered a unique identifier (for files that are all in the same directory/repository.) So that could be the file's key.

- Advantages: Easier to import. All references to that file are human readable.
- Disadvantages: each reference to that file uses more database space than an integer key. If a file is renamed it looks like a new file; the name can't change without changing the key. (Although, there are workarounds.)

The import will be much easier without assigning unique integer keys. I suggest you import first, then optionally add integer keys afterwards.

Import: put the data in the CSV files, one file per table. Then import them into the destination database in the correct order. (If I understand your structure correctly the first one would be the Repository table, as Commits and Changes both refer to it.)

Adding integer keys to existing tables: Add an autonumbering column to each table that needs an integer key. So each parent row now has it's original unique name and an integer ID. Then you can use SQL commands to replace each parent name in a child table with it's respective internal key, then drop the extra name columns once they are no longer needed.